# IEEE 754: Where "the rounded result is within 0.5 ULP of the mathematically exact result" implication can be seen?

Tags: floating-point, precision, ieee-754, floating-accuracy

From ULP [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) (emphasis added):

> The IEEE 754 specification—followed by all modern floating-point hardware—requires that the result of an elementary arithmetic operation (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and square root since 1985, and FMA since 2008) be correctly rounded, which *implies that in rounding to nearest, the rounded result is within 0.5 ULP of the mathematically exact result*, using John Harrison's definition;

Question: Where exactly the implication emphasized above can be seen?

Comment: On a line segment AB of length d, what is the farthest any point P on the segment can be from the closer of A or B?

Comment: Correct, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... that in rounding to nearest, the rounded result is within 0.5 ULP of the mathematically exact result, using John Harrison's definition;

> Where exactly the implication emphasized above can be seen?

Near powers-of-2. (or whatever base)

Consider using ULP as [quantum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66637497/2410359) vs. [John Harrison's definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66637497/2410359).

In a neighborhood of a power-of-2 as `p` and its least encoded FP digit as `u`, the representable floating point values are [p-u, p-u/2, p, p+u, p+2u] for a base 2 system.

With **quantum**, the ULP of those 5 values are [u/2, u/2, u, u, u].

If the exact answer to some math operation is exactly `p`, then `p` "within 0.5 ULP " includes  [p-u/2, p], thus allowing the inferior `p-u/2` as an acceptable answer.

With **John Harrison**, the ULP of those 5 values are [u/2, u/2, u/2, u, u].

The ULP of a value `p` as a power-of-2 is *half as big* as with quantum and so only `p` is an acceptable answer.

---

Ref: [Unit in the Last Place - ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)