# Difference between ULP (unit in the last place) and quantum (IEEE 754)

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

From [ULP Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place):

> Another definition, suggested by John Harrison, is slightly different: ULP(x) is the distance between the two closest straddling floating-point numbers a and b (i.e., those with a ≤ x ≤ b and a ≠ b), assuming that the exponent range is not upper-bounded.

From IEEE 754 2008:

> 2.1.44 quantum: The quantum of a finite floating-point representation is the value of a unit in the last position of its significand. This is equal to the radix raised to the exponent q, which is used when the significand is regarded as an integer.

Question: What is the difference between `ULP` (John Harrison's definition) and `quantum` (from IEEE 754)?

Do I understand right that quantum of `double x` can be computed as:

```c
double ulp(double x)
{
        int exp;
        frexp( x, &exp );
        return ldexp( 0.5, exp-52 );
}
double quantum(double x)
{
        int exp;
        return ulp(frexp( x, &exp ));
}
```

Comment: The IEEE-754 definition applies only to floating-point numbers (the real numbers that are representable in the floating-point format); it does not provide a definition for real numbers between floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between ULP (John Harrison's definition) and quantum (from IEEE 754)?

[edit]

OP's `quantum()` appears incorrect, consistently returning `1.11022e-16` for all finite `x`, even when `x` is a sub-normal.

Rest of answer assumes `quantum()` is more like `quantum_alt()` below which has the same result for each [power-of-2 ... 2*power-of-2).  Note the `[)`.

**Power of the radix**

When `x` is a power-of-the-base [These definitions differ only at signed powers of the radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place#Definition)

For [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), consider when **`x` is a power-of-2**.  The next larger FP value is `x + u` and the next smaller value is `x - u/2`.

John Harrison: "distance between the two closest straddling floating-point numbers a and b (i.e., those with a ≤ x ≤ b and a ≠ b)" implies `a` is the smaller value and `x == b` and ULP is `u/2`.<sup>1</sup>

Quantum: "representation is the value of a unit in the last position of its significand" implies the `ULP` is `u`.

The  distance `b-a` is 1/2 the "quantum" definition; `a` being in the smaller exponent subrange than `x` and whose last position significant is half of `x`.

---

**Applicability**

Definitions also differ in that both apply to floating point values, but not *quantum* with [real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) values like 1/7, √2, π.  [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637497/difference-between-ulp-unit-in-the-last-place-and-quantum-ieee-754/66640220#comment117800427_66637497)

---

Both OP functions are wrong in select cases.

`ulp()` per John Harrison, is amiss when `x` is a power-of-2, zero or a sub-normal.
Alternate

```
#include <math.h>

// Using the convention ULP(x) == ULP(-x)
// Adjust if you want a signed result.
double ulp_JH(double x) {
  x = fabs(x);
  if (isfinite(x)) {
    double lower = nextafter(x, -1.0); // 1st FP number smaller than x   
    return x - lower;
  }
  return x; // NAN, infinity
}
```

OP's `quantum()` is amiss when `x` is a zero or a sub-normal.

```
double quantum_alt(double x) {
  x = fabs(x);
  if (x < DBL_MAX) {
    double higher = nextafter(x, DBL_MAX); // 1st FP number larger than x   
    return higher - x;
  }
  if (isfinite(x)) {
    double lower = nextafter(x, 0.0); // Special case for DBL_MAX
    return x - lower;
  }
  return x; // NAN, infinity
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Except when `x == DBL_TRUE_MIN`.  In that case. `ULP(DBL_TRUE_MIN)` is `DBL_TRUE_MIN`.

Comment: pmor, Curious, what is the application to use either `ulp()` and/or `quantum()`?

Comment: (1) "Both OP functions are wrong in select cases": the implementation of `ulp` was taken from the paper by S. L. Abrams, W. Cho, C.-Y. Hu, T. Maekawa, N. M. Patrikalakis, E. C. Sherbrooke, and X. Ye. _Efficient and reliable methods for rounded-interval arithmetic_. Computer-Aided Design, 30(8):657-665, July 1998, PDF available at https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.90.5051&rep=rep1&type=pdf (page 5). Can you please check whether their implementation is correct? Does Maekawa et al. assume John Harrison's definition of the ULP?

Comment: (2) "the application to use either ulp()": I used `ulp()` in implementation of `sqrt()` function for "final adjustment" step: see description in file https://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_sqrt.c: see "Other methods (use floating-point arithmetic)" => "sqrt(x) by Reciproot Iteration" => "(3) Final adjustment". Note: code in `e_sqrt.c` is not my code, I used this code as a reference. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450864/ieee-754-conformant-sqrt-implementation-for-double-type.

Comment: @pmor Your `ulp()` of a sub-normal returns 0.0 - certainly not a desired outcome.  (Not likely exercised as a result form `sqrt()`)  `ulp()` as a power of 2 differs from  John Harrison definition.  My understanding of `quantum()` is amiss, will update later.

Comment: (1) Yes, `certainly not a desired outcome` is true. Yes, `sqrt(DBL_TRUE_MIN)` gives `2.222759E-162`, which is normal, however, `ulp(sqrt(DBL_TRUE_MIN))` and `ulp_JH(sqrt(DBL_TRUE_MIN))` produce `0x1p-589` and `0x1p-590` respectively. Shall I use `ulp_JH` for for the "final adjustment" step in `sqrt()` implementation?
(2) Updated `quantum()`: ok, thanks, need time to understand it.

Comment: @pmor " Shall I use ulp_JH for for the "final adjustment" step in sqrt() implementation?" --> your call.  I see `ulp_JH()` as more mathematically correct, yet `quantum_alt()` easier to explain.  I prefer a 3rd approach to rate  functions that I will detail someday elsewhere.

Comment: _I will detail someday elsewhere_: Just don't forget that _someday_ may not happen, cause there is a probability _p1_ of being infected by COVID-19 and, hence, a probability _p2_ of passing away. I'd not postpone it.

Comment: @pmor p2 is 100% for [most of us](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/who-never-died-in-the-bible).  IAC, the idea is not fully fleshed out.

Comment: I'd progressively send the drafts to some trusted people (multiple copies to multiple persons). If something will happen, the drafts won't be lost.

Comment: FYI: My test shows that GNU [`ulp`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/b92a49359f33a461db080a33940d73f47c756126/math/libm-test-support.c#L580) for `DBL_MIN` returns `0.0` instead of `0x1p-1074` (`DBL_TRUE_MIN`).

Comment: It seems that GNU `ulp` produces wrong result (`0.0`) for values in range `DBL_MIN` .. `0x1.ffffffffffffcp-1024` (`nextafter(0x1p-1023, -1.0)`).